# Build Kubernetes cluster with spark master and spark workers

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes

I've built a custom-spark docker image with the following dependencies:

- Python 3.6.9
- Pip 1.18
- Java OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_212
- Hadoop 3.2
- Scala 2.13.0
- Spark 3.0.3

where I pushed to ducker hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/redaer7/custom-spark

Dockerfile,spark-master and spark-worker files are stored under: https://github.com/redaER7/Custom-Spark

I verify `/spark-master` and `/spark-worker` works well when creating a container linked to the previous image:

```
docker run -it -d --name spark_1 redaer7/custom-spark:1.0 bash
```

```
docker exec -it $CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
```

[image]

[image]

My issue is when I try to build a K8s cluster from previous image with following yaml file for the spark master pod:

```
kubectl create namespace sparkspace
kubectl -n sparkspace create -f ./spark-master-deployment.yaml
```

```
#yaml file
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: spark-master
spec:
  replicas: 1 # should always be one
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: spark-master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: spark-master
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: spark-master
          image: redaer7/custom-spark:1.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: ["/spark-master"]
          ports:
          - containerPort: 7077
          - containerPort: 8080
          resources:
          #  limits:
          #    cpu: 1
          #    memory: 1G
            requests:
              cpu: 1 #100m
              memory: 1G
```

I get `CrashLoopBackOff` when viewing pod with `kubectl -n sparkspace get pods`

When inspecting with `kubectl -n sparkspace describe pod $Pod_Name`

[image]

Any clue about that First warning ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply solved it by re-pulling the image :

```
imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Because I edited the Docker Image locally and I haven't changed the following in the config file:

```
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Then, I pushed it into Dockerhub for later deployment